# string issue with strstr()

Tags: c, visual-studio

I need to count how many times a smaller string is in bigger string with strstr(),
and I know that when using strstr() it will put the pointer in the spot where the smaller string is found in bigger string. But I don't know what kind of a loop I should write to check that how many times this smaller string is presented in this bigger string? So in this case the correct answer would be 3.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_substr(const char *str, const char *sub) {
    int i = 0;
    int res;
    res = strstr(str, sub);
    if (res) {
        i++;
    }
    else {
        i = i;
    }
    return i;

}
int main(void) {
    char lol[] = "one two one twotwo three";
    char asd[] = "two";
    int ret;
    ret = count_substr(lol, asd);
    printf("%d", ret);


}
```

Comment: `strstr` return `char *` not `int`..

Comment: What should `count_substr("ababa", "aba")` return 1 or 2?

Comment: this case got solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop like this:

```
int count_substr(const char *str, const char *sub) {
    int cnt = 0;
    char *found;

    while(found = strstr(str, sub))
    {
        cnt++;
        str = found + 1;
    }

    return cnt;
}
```

The interesting part is this:

```
str = found + 1;
```

because you are not interested in the characters before the found substring, you
can safely ignore them and advance `str` to the next character after the found
substring. `strstr` eventually will return `NULL` when no substring is found or
when `str[0] == 0` after it reaches the end of the string.

**edit**

I put this in the answer because the comment section is far to restricted for
longer comments.

`found` is a pointer to `char`. Whether it's pointing to a single `char` object
or to the start of a sequence of bytes or the start of a string, depends on the
context. The context here is that `found` is assigned with the return value of
the function `strstr`.

> *man strstr*
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
>
> char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `strstr()` function finds the first occurrence of the substring `needle` in the string `haystack`.
>   The terminating null bytes (`'\0'`) are not compared.
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> [This function returns] a pointer to the beginning of the located substring, or `NULL` if the substring is not found.

On success `strstr` returns a pointer to the location of the source where the substring is
found. So `found` will return a pointer to `"two one twotwo three"`.

`found + 1` is pointer arithmetic and it's the same as doing `&(found[1])` which will return
a pointer to the next `char` in the sequence. `found + 1` will point to 
`"wo one twotwo three"` and this pointer it will be assigned to `str`, so that
`str` points to the **next** character after the found substring.

If I don't do
that, I would have created an endless loop, because `strstr` would keep
returning the same substring, over and over.

So the next time `strstr(str, sub)` is executed, `found` will point to
`"twotwo three"`, and `found + 1` will return a pointer to `"wotwo three"`, and
so on.

In case that the substring is not found, it will return `NULL` the loop ends. At
that point it doesn't matter that `found` is also pointing to `NULL`.

Comment: This definitely worked, thank you sir! but like so first when you put 'found = strstr(str, sub)' then the 'found' will either be as an integer the spot where the first 'two' is on the string or  'found' as a char will be string "two one twotwo three" and when we write 'str = found + 1' at the end of the loop then the first character will be skipped so the string looks like this "wo one twotwo three" right?

Comment: this fails to allow for overlapping sub strings, so fail certain test cases

Comment: @user3629249 Perhaps post an example failing case with  overlapping sub string.  I do not see the failure yet given OP's [goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48631075/string-issue-with-strstr#comment84260054_48631075)  (Hmmm OP removed the comment of wanting 2 with `count_substr("ababa", "aba")`)  I guess a good lesson in coding to a customer's incomplete or moving target.

Comment: @michael I've made an update of my answer addressing your comment.

Comment: @user3629249 this is just a simple algorithm, so it won't cover all cases you can think of. The OP's requirements are not clear enough to count all special cases, the OP was more interested in knowing how to use a function `strstr` in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The function `strstr()` returns a `char` pointer, not an `int`, so the variable to be assigned its returned value should be of type `char *`. You can use this value to loop over a string and find the number of sub-strings in it; A `while` loop would suffice:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int count_substr(const char *str, const char *sub)
{
    int i = 0;
    size_t sub_len = strlen(sub);
    const char *res = strstr(str, sub);
    while (res)
    {
        i++;
        str = res + sub_len;
        res = strstr(str, sub);
    }
    return i;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char lol[] = "one two one twotwo three";
    char asd[] = "two";
    int ret = count_substr(lol, asd);
    printf("ret: %d\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For `count_substr("ababa", "aba")`, this will return 1.  OP may/may not want 2.  OP's goal in this case is not clear.

Comment: Unfortunate OP did not detail initially coding goals, [until later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48631075/string-issue-with-strstr#comment84260054_48631075), concerning overlapped sub-strings.

Comment: @chux I just read the OP's last comment. He said `2`! so, I have deleted my prev comment.

Comment: @chux what does *UV* stands for?

Comment: @pablo Up-Vote, not Ultra-Violet :):)

Answer (score 0):

```
res = strstr(str, sub);
```

### the variable `res` should be declared as `char *res;` rather than `int res;` because the function: `strstr()` returns a `char*` not a `int`.  This error causes the compiler to output a warning message. You should have seen that warning and corrected it before posting the question.

what is this:

```
i = i;
```

### supposed to accomplish?

the following proposed code:

1. documents why each header file is being included
2. properly calculates the number of times a substring is contained in a string, including any overlapping sub strings.
3. appropriately includes indenting, horizontal spacing, vertical spacing, etc for ease of readability and understanding
4. uses meaningful variable names

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf()
#include <string.h>  // strstr()

// prototypes
int count_substr( const char *str, const char *sub );


int main(void)
{
    char lol[] = "one two one twotwo three";
    char asd[] = "two";

    int ret = count_substr( lol, asd );
    printf( "%d\n", ret );   // '\n' so immediately displayed on terminal
}


int count_substr( const char *str, const char *sub )
{
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;
    char *oldres = NULL;
    char *newres = NULL;

    do
    {
        newres = strstr( &str[index], sub );
        index++;

        if( newres != oldres && newres )
            count++;

        oldres = newres;
    } while( oldres );

    return count;
}
```